# Can Copy and Paste work on textBlock,WebPage and other on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to know if the following can be done base on Windows Phone Update for Copy and paste function.

1) can copy and paste function works on :

1.1 TextBlock inside an App

Hightlight it for copy and paste

1.2. TextBox in SMS ( Native SMS )

Select a SMS in the SMS inbox and hightlight the received Message for copy and paste

1.3. WebPage. ( open by WebBrowser Control or Native Browser)

I want to hightlight a text ( the text can be english or non-English) for 
copy and paste

2) after I have done the Copy for the above (1.1, 1.2, 1.3) , now I want to open my Wp7 App and paste (Either 1.1 or 1.2 or 1.3) into a TextBox.

can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no implementation of the Copy/Paste mechanism for `TextBlock` and derived static text controls. The text entry panel in the native SMS application, as well as web pages, should support it, though, as long as you have the latest update that introduces this system capability.

The clipboard will be indirectly accessible (the user will be able to paste the copied material in your app) but you aren't able to control the clipboard (in this release of the SDK).

Comment: The Wp7 UPdate contain CopyPaste is not availabe yet. But Happ to hear the capabilities. Just for confirmation, Is this what I said can be done. Say, I receive a SMS, I start Copyandpaste the text, then Open My App and paste it in the textBox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an update released for the sdk of phone 7.
It the initial stages it wasn't allowed to copy and paste..

But according to the new sdk it allows copy and paste..
You might want to try downloading the new sdk...
all the best..